# pyspark RDD - add list of tuples at some index

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a RDD that looks like this

```
[( 3,6,7), (2,5,7), (4,3,7)]
```

I would like to get the average of first elements , as well as sum of the second elements and sum of third elements. This is how the output would look:

```
(3,14,21)
```

Is it possible to do this using pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to a dataframe and use `groupBy`:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

# toy data
rdd = sc.parallelize([(3,6,7), (2,5,7), (4,3,7)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,("x1", "x2", "x3"))

(df.groupBy().avg("x1").collect()[0][0],
 df.groupBy().sum('x2').collect()[0][0],
 df.groupBy().sum('x3').collect()[0][0])
# (3.0, 14, 21)
```

Or you could group the 2 `sum` operations:

```python
ave = df.groupBy().avg("x1").collect()
sums = df.groupBy().sum("x2","x3").collect()
(ave[0][0], sums[0][0], sums[0][1])
# (3.0, 14, 21)
```

UPDATE (after comment): user8371915's proposal leads to an even more elegant solution:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, sum

num_cols = len(df.columns) # number of columns
res = df.groupBy().agg(avg("x1"), sum("x2"), sum("x3")).first()
[res[i] for i in range(num_cols)]
# [3.0, 14, 21]
```

Answer (score 2):

With RDD you can use NumPy array and stats:

```python
import numpy as np 

stats = sc.parallelize([( 3,6,7), (2,5,7), (4,3,7)]).map(np.array).stats()
stats.mean()[0], stats.sum()[1], stats.sum()[2]

# (3.0, 14.0, 21.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible in pyspark. You can use dataframe functionality to get all these values. Please try below.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

my_rdd=sc.parallelize([( 3,6,7), (2,5,7), (4,3,7)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(my_rdd,("fld1", "fld2", "fld3"))
df.groupBy().agg(avg(col("fld1")),sum(col("fld2")),sum(col("fld3"))).rdd.collect()
```

Another way of doing it:

```python
df.registerTempTable('mytable')
df1=sqlContext.sql("select avg(fld1), sum(fld2), sum(fld3) from mytable")
df1.rdd.collect()
```

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: This gives `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'avg'`

Comment: Can you try it with mean. It is also works as avg in dataframes.

Comment: It does, but not after `sum` - please check again, and include the output you produce!

Comment: Sure, I will provide the details by tomorrow. On my current machine set up is not there. Else I have one more option if you can try that.  Remove group by and the regsiter temp table from df.registerTempTable('table_name') and the use sqlContext.sql("select avg(fld1), sum(fld2),sum(fld3) from table_name"). I hope this will help. I will check the shared ans and will update with details.

Comment: Have already answered... And please, *do not post code in the comments space* - it s literally unreadable! Edit your post instead!

Comment: Sure. I will update in post and take care of that. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160375/discussion-between-manu-gupta-and-desertnaut).